# INSERT new row and MKDIR with the name of that inserted row ID

Tags: php, mysql, mkdir

The page has to INSERT a row and MAKE a directory with the name of the ID of that row when the user clicks the upload button, will this script work?, what could possibly go wrong?.

> (when the upload button has been clicked)
>   //insert the new row
>   $query="INSERT
>   INTO photoalbum (userid) VALUES
>   ($userid)";
>   mysql_query($query);
>
> //get the id of that row to make a
>   directory with that name
>   $getid="SELECT
>   id FROM photoalbum WHERE userid =
>   $userid order by id desc limit 1";
>   $result=mysql_query($getid);
>   $thename=mysql_results($result,0,"id");
>   mkdir('userimages/$userid/photoalbums/$thename');
>
> {   script that upload the files in the new folder  }

Is it safe to INSERT and SELECT the row I just inserted in the same page, just right after an insert has been done? I was thinking what if the SELECT query don't pick the row i just inserted but instead the previous row, because the INSERT isnt fast enough and the SELECT query gets the previous row instead. Is this a possible scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `mysql_insert_id()` ?

As for your question if the insert is successful, then there is no problem with doing a select even a millisecond after the insert.

I just noticed another problem:

```
mkdir('userimages/$userid/photoalbums/$thename');
```

Due to single quotes the $userid and $thename variables will be used literally, so instead use double quotes like this:

```
mkdir("userimages/$userid/photoalbums/$thename");
```

Comment: i had no idea that mysql_insert_id existed, im fairly new to php. thanks

Comment: Yup its a pretty handy thing to have, it would erase the need of your select query altogether.

Comment: I added more info to my answer, hopefully it will resolve your problem.